# Convergence of a integral: $\int_{0}^{1} |\ln (x)|^n \ dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $n \in \mathbb N$ be arbitrary. Does the integral
$$\int_{0}^{1} |\ln (x)|^n \, dx$$
converge? I asked myself this question and I have no idea of a proof or counter example. Someone can give me a help?

Comment: This is Euler's first integral expression for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#History). It evaluates to $n!$ for $n>-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem is at $0$. The absolute value is irrelevant (just multiply by $(-1)^{n+1}$ the final result when no absolute value is used), so we can consider
$$
\int_a^1(\log x)^n\,dx
$$
with $a>0$.
An integration by parts gives
$$
\Bigl[x(\log x)^n\Bigr]_a^1-\int_a^1 x\cdot n(\log x)^{n-1}\frac{1}{x}\,dx
$$
Can you go on from here?

Answer (score 2):

For $n$ even and $a>0$:
$\int_{a}^{1} |lnx|^n dx=\int_{a}^{1}(x)^{'}(lnx)^ndx=xlnx_{a}^{1}-\int_{a}^{1}xn(lnx)^{n-1}\frac {1}{x}dx=xlnx_{a}^{1}-\int_{a}^{1}n(lnx)^{n-1}dx$. By induction $\int_{a}^{1} (lnx)^{n}dx$ converges iff $\int_{a}^{1} lnx dx$ converges.

Same tactic for $n$ odd.